# Is there a way to access hive metastore tables from HCATALOG?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog, metastore

In my application, I am using hive metastore(mysql) from JDBC. Now the requirement got changed and I won't be able to get metastore credentials. Hence I can't use JDBC to access metastore.

I wanted to know, Is there a way to access hivemetastore tables like TBLS and INDXS from HCATALOG? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to access the meta tables directly?  HCatalog does give you a good amount of info, but not direct access to the meta tables.

Comment: Hi climbage. Exactly you understood my question. I need direct access to hive meta tables like "TBLS" which contains all hive table details. Isn't it possible through Hcatalog ?

Comment: Climbage, please let me know where can I find "what info Hcatalog can give us?"

Comment: Start [here](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/class-use/Table.html). You can get all if this through hive client and hcatalog.

Comment: Ill try to make a better answer when I get to a real computer (on my phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get most of the information you need through HCatalog, without direct access to the metastore tables.

```
HiveConf conf = new HiveConf(); // should pull hive-site.xml automatically
HiveMetaStoreClient hiveClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(conf);
Table hiveTable = HCatUtil.getTable(hiveClient, "default", "sometable");

... = hiveTable.getAllIndexes(max);
```

Comment: Thanks climbage. Some how managed to get task done. This is working for getPartCols, getAllCols. But for getAllIndexes, it is not returning the indexes even the hive table have indexes. I tried by setting max to combinations like -1, 1,0, 100 like this. Exactly what is this max param refers in getAllIndexes function. I mean number of indexes? or ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what HCatalog is all about: access and manipulate the metastore. See [SHOW TABLES](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+CLI#HCatalogCLI-SHOWTABLES).

Comment: Hi Remus Rusanu, \n I have checked hcatalog "Show Tables" command. It is displaying only hive tables. Not hive metastore tables like TBLS. I googled a bit and came to know that, hcatalog will work on hive metastore just like hive. But it may not able to display metastore tables. If you have any idea how can i access hive metastore tables(not hive tables) through hcatalog.

Comment: Sry, misunderstood your question. You want access to the metastore tables, not to the tables store d in metastores. I have to ask *why*? What is the original problem, why can't you use HCatalog API to manipulate the content and not sneak in the inner workings of the metastore itself?

Comment: For example, if you wnat to list all the hive indexes associated with a table? will it be possible with out metadata. For this kind of requirements I have used metastore earlier. Now I need to find whether the same thing can be achieved in any other way? One of the thought I got is, can I access metastore tables from Hcatalog.